# How to draw Japanese text with SkiaSharp on Xamarin

Tags: android, xamarin, skiasharp

Now I'm using SkiaSharp on Xamarin Android.

I wanna draw Japanese text with SKCanvas.DrawText ,but japanese characters were garbled.

I saw this 
[similar question](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/skia-discuss/ys_1Wvq5D3k/i2yn97vT0XsJ),so I tried to convert text to UTF-8, but result is same.

I tried like below.

```
var s = "abcあいう123壱弐参";
var buf = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(s);
var utf8s = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buf);
skcanvas.DrawText(utf8s, 50, 50, paint);
```

another one.

```
var s = "abcあいう123壱弐参";
var dest = Encoding.UTF8;
var src = Encoding.Default;
var buf = src.GetBytes(s);
var buf2 = Encoding.Convert(src,dest, buf);
var utf8s = dest.GetString(buf2);
skcanvas.DrawText(utf8s, 50, 50, paint);
```

Both result are same. "abc" and "123" is drawn well,but Japanese character are garbled.

Any idea?

Answer (score 5):

Assuming you are loading a custom font, like [Uzumasa Honmaru Gothic](http://www.flopdesign.com/marugothic/uzumasa-font.html), you can add it to each of your native platform project and then use it via that native project or a `Xamarin.Forms`-based one:

#### Android:

```
string fontName = "UzumasaFontMini.otf";
string fontPath = Path.Combine (CacheDir.AbsolutePath, fontName);
using (var asset = Assets.Open (fontName))
using (var dest = File.Open (fontPath, FileMode.Create)) {
    asset.CopyTo (dest);
}
string customFontPath = fontPath;
```

#### iOS:

```
string fontName = "UzumasaFontMini.otf";
string customFontPath = NSBundle.MainBundle.PathForResource (Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension (fontName), Path.GetExtension (fontName));
```

#### DrawText:

```
string text = "abcあいう123";
using (var paint = new SKPaint ()) {
    canvas.Clear (SKColors.Black);
    paint.IsAntialias = true;

    using (var tf = SKTypeface.FromFile (customFontPath)) {
        paint.Color = SKColors.White;
        paint.TextSize = 20;
        paint.Typeface = tf;

        canvas.DrawText (text, 50, 50, paint);
    }
}
```

Android:

[image]

iOS:

[image]

Comment: Thank you.
I can draw Japanese as you did.
But I wanna use default or system font instead of loading custom font.
I can get SKTypeface from UIFont.FamilyName by SKTypeface.FromFamilyName on iOS.
Do you know how to do on Android?

Answer (score 2):

You can use "matchCharacter()", input param might be just a Japanese character, like "あ"

```
var japanese = fontManager.MatchCharacter("Courier New", '年')
paint.Typeface = japanese;
canvas.DrawText("abcあいう123", x, 300, paint);
```

Refer link: https://github.com/mono/SkiaSharp/blob/master/samples/SkiaSharpSample.Shared/Samples/UnicodeTextSample.cs

Comment: You Sir are a god damn legend. :) This fixed the issue I had with my project.